# Event handler calls anonymous function within for loop, however event handler attaches to last element only

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, mouseevent, anonymous-function

I have multiple divs which showcase some of the projects I have worked on(lets call each div's class **project**) . When project is hovered over(Jquery's MouseOver), a div that is contained within it (lets call each class of this type   **githublink**) which has a link to the GitHub account and the website link for that respective project fades in, and vice versa for mouseleave and fadeout. The design acts exactly as how I expect it to react, however when I hover over any of the five project div's the last project div's githublink is always the one fading in and fading out. I concluded that the reason for this is because of the for loop I am using to assign the mouseOver and MouseLeave Events. I am only going to include this specific javascript code and not the HTML code because I have debugged the javascript code and looked at the Chrome Dev Tools and found that after each iteration of the for loop the right element is being retrieved and assigned, however once the for loop is done all the eventhandlers affect the last GitHubDiv. 
 **Below Is My JS Code**

```
var numprojects=document.getElementsByClassName("project");
    console.log(numprojects.length);
if(numprojects){
    for(i=0; i<=numprojects.length-1; i++){
        console.log(i);
        currentclass=".project:eq("+i+")";
        currentgithublink=".githublink:eq("+i+")";
        if($(currentclass)){
            $(currentclass).mouseover(function(){
                $(currentgithublink).fadeIn("fast","linear");
            })
            $(currentclass).mouseleave(function(){
                $(currentgithublink).fadeOut("fast","linear");

            })
        }
    }
}
```

How to rewrite the same code using a for loop to save space but at the same time to avoid this issue. I think it has something to do with the anonymous functions, but most importantly **WHY** and how to fix it.

**UPDATE
After reading about closure, I updated my code to do the following now an event isnt triggered at all for any of the projects. **

```
if(numprojects){
    console.log("entered projects");
    for(i=0; i<=numprojects.length-1; i++){
        console.log("entered loop");
        mouse[i]=".project:eq("+i+")";
        currentgithublink[i]=".githublink:eq("+i+")";

        $(mouse[i]).mouseover=(function(index){
            return function(){
                $(currentgithublink[i]).fadeIn("fast","linear");
            }

        })

        $(mouse[i]).mouseleave=(function(index){
            return function(){
                $(currentgithublink[i]).fadeOut("fast","linear");
            }

        })

    }
}
```

**2ND UPDATE** Tried a different method... Still cant figure out why this wont work

```
    var currentclass=[];
    mouseover=[];
    mouseleave=[];

if(numprojects){
    for(i=0; i<=numprojects.length-1; i++){
        currentclass[i]=".project:eq("+i+")";
        mouseover[i]=getFadeIn(i);
        mouseleave[i]=getFadeOut(i);
        $(currentclass[i]).mouseover=mouseover[i];
        $(currentclass[i]).mouseleave=mouseleave[i];

    }


}   

function getFadeIn(i){
    currentgithublink=".githublink:eq("+i+")";
        return function(){
            $(currentgithublink).fadeIn("fast","linear");
        }
}
function getFadeOut(i){
    currentgithublink=".githublink:eq("+i+")";
        return function(){
            $(currentgithublink).fadeOut("fast","linear");
        }
}
```

Comment: Need to pay more attention to what you are checking in your `if()` statements. `if($(currentclass))` will always be truthy even if no element matching exists because `$(selector)` always returns an object and objects are truthy. Would use `if($(currentclass).length)`

Comment: There is a closure created in the loop with statements `currentclass=".project:eq("+i+")";
        currentgithublink=".githublink:eq("+i+")";` So, i would be the last index always as the value of `i` closes over the loop.

Comment: `currentgithublink` will always be last index of loop at time event occurs

Comment: @Agalo should say *"there is **no** closure"*

Comment: @charlietfl wouldn't the statement `currentgithublink=".githublink:eq("+i+")";`  would always have `i = numprojects.length-1` inside the handlers ?

Comment: @Agalo  how to provide closure?

Comment: @charlietfl why will it always be the last index. I know the issue of my problem.

Comment: @charlietfl just saw that someone posted an answer just like this. Thanks

Comment: Because the loop completes instantly...and each iteration overwrites `currentgithublink` and you don't use that until the event actually occurs. Go through the duplicate link for a thorough understanding

Comment: there is actually one currentgithublink sting that exists on the closure of the anonymous function,  add this line outside : items = [] and then replace  currentclass=".project:eq("+i+")"; currentgithublink=".githublink:eq("+i+")"; by var item = {currentclass:".project:eq("+i+")",  currentgithublink:".githublink:eq("+i+")"}
items.push(item) and then in the other lines replace all currentclass by item.currentclass and currentgithublink by item.currentgithublink

Comment: @challenger Check the most updated code

Comment: @charlietfl Check the most updated code

Comment: @Agalo Check the most updated code

Comment: one simple way is switch out `for` loop with `$.each` in original code....then `i` will be in a closure

Comment: you don't need array of mouseover and mouseleave !!! actually you only need an array of currentgithublink... only those insde the callback function must not be changed in the closure...so it's only one array of  currentgithublink, keep the first code with and try var currentgithublink = [] .... Sorry I can't write the code in a comment!

Comment: I was reading the code and testing it.. I really now understand the problem but I'm not sure how to solve it.. I  think it can't be solved for one closure... let say that numprojects.length ==30 , then there must be 30 closures! so you may need to put the for loop out of the anonymous function... I think there is no other solution for!